# If I'm already in a transaction do I still need to SELECT FOR UPDATE()?

Tags: postgresql

If I'm already in a transaction **do I still need to SELECT FOR UPDATE()?**

Example:

```sql
BEGIN

-- Is this FOR UPDATE still needed here? I'm in a transaction!
SELECT * FROM "players" ORDER BY "number desc" WHERE LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE

-- 321 here is the lastest number from previous SELECT FOR UPDATE + 1
INSERT INTO "players" ("id", "number", "note") VALUES (DEFAULT, 321, DEFAULT) RETURNING "id"

UPDATE "players" SET "note" = 'Test' WHERE "id" = 1

COMMIT
```

Comment: How would it work without a transaction? And yes, it's absolutely necessary to tell the transaction what you want to do, otherwise it can't provide guarantees for it.

Comment: I mean, you can only have row-level locks within a transaction anyway. So yes, there is a difference between transactions with locking statements and transactions without locking statements. What do you believe a transaction does that would allow you to omit the `SELECT FOR UPDATE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question doesn't make much formal sense, as a SELECT can only happen inside a transaction, even if it is only a one-statement-long one.

In your example, your third statement bares no obvious relationship to the first two.  What is the overall transaction supposed to accomplish?

Looking just at the first two statements, it looks like you are trying to avoid inserting the same "next" value twice by two concurrent sessions.  If both sessions are using serializable isolation level or if you have a unique constraint, then the FOR UPDATE is indeed unnecessary, as serialization failure or unique key violations will prevent that from happening anyway.  Of course that does mean you need to catch and retry.

If they are using the default read committed isolation level and with no unique constraint, then FOR UPDATE is also unnecessary, but for an odd reason.  The FOR UPDATE is actually not effective at accomplishing the goal, and if your code is going to be wrong it might as well be wrong without a FOR UPDATE.